# How to destructure a function from props Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this interface that I want to destructure into props. The problem is, destructuring assignment of `function` is not working. This function is simply a function that is run at a lower-level component.  Do I have a syntax error? Also, why can I not export the const as default?

```ts
interface Props {
    day: string;
    options: string[];
    id: string;
    function: () => void;
}

// React FN component
export const group = ({ day, options, id , function } : Props) => {

    // Component logic 
}
```

Comment: I think function is a reserved keyword, that is why. Change function to fnc in both places and check?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is asking two different things (`function` assignment and `export default` not working). It is fine to have multiple questions but they should be just that: two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function` is a reserved keyword. I would try to name is something more descriptive as to what its purpose is. Or, you can use `callback` if it needs to be generic.

You can have a default const export by doing the following.

```
const group = ({ day, options, id , callback } : Props)...

export default group;
```

Answer (score 3):

`function` is a reserved keyword in javascript & typescript. If you rename the `function` property to `fn` or something else then your code no longer gives an error.

```js
interface Props {
  day: string;
  options: string[];
  id: string;
  fn: () => void;
}

// React FN component
export const group = ({ day, options, id , fn} : Props) => {

// Component logic 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
    interface Props {
  day: string;
  options: string[];
  id: string;
  fn: () => void;
}

// React FN component
export const group: React.FC<Props> = ({ day, options, id , fn}) => {

// You can use children, defaultProps 
}
```

This FC means FunctionalComponent. It provides children, defaultProps fields.